# Is there any benefit of using if statement with logical operator?

Tags: java, c++, c

I know that *if statements* can be used in various ways, such as an if statement with a logical operator, *if...else*, and *nested if statements* etc.

When using a logical operator such as &&, || to confirm a lot of conditions, then code size becomes smaller than when using multiple nested if statements. Is there any other benefit (run time, debugging, compile time benefit etc.) of using this if statement with conditional operator?

Comment: Can you provide some example code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: do be honest, I am not sure what "conditional operators" are

Comment: @gefei, `something ? anything : anything_else`

Comment: One of the main drawbacks of conditional operator is that it decreases  code readability, specially when you use it instead of large nested if...else statements. I Think there is no difference (from compiler perspective) between these two options.

Comment: The IOCCC, I think...

Comment: I think he means `if ( A && B )` in comparison to `if ( A ) { if ( B ) }`. It's easier in the latter to give a detailled error message.

Comment: @moghaddam Agree for the most part, but whether that makes a difference to the compiler is language specific, in C++ it *might* make a difference depending on compiler and optimization settings...

Comment: @ Newer please clear what are you asking? As you can see in comments that everyone is coming with some new guess.So now its your turn to make change in OP for clarity

Comment: if(condition 1)
{if (condition 2)
{if (Condition 3){statement 1;}
else nothing;}
else nothing;}
else statement 3;

if (condition 1 && condition 2 && condition 3)
{statement 1;}
else statement 2;

I know in 2nd time it is easier to read and write. My question is, is there any other benefit of using the second one??

Comment: Turns out I got the question wrong...

Comment: I got it right. ...anyway. @Newer could you please edit the question, add the code & make it more readable.

Comment: actually I am not working with any code. I just want to know is there any other benefit or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One feature you need to consider while making the decision is [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

That means when you use conditional operators over nested if statements  the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression.

Comment: Further conditions in nested if-statements are also only evaluated if the former ones hold.

Comment: which is why the order in which they are evaluated is important.

Comment: then is it a very big benefit?

Comment: @AniketThakur - The OP has confused us by *incorrectly* using the term "conditional" when he actually means something else.  Look at his example.

Comment: Your're right. I apologize

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I have edited my question.

Comment: @Newer Just a further hint for the future. Code on StackOverflow is formatted with the **{}**-Symbol or with backticks, e. g. \`if (A && B)\` the output is `if (A && B)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance advantage in using the conditional operator versus using an `if` statement.  If the two versions of the code are equivalent, there is no reason to expect that the JIT compiler won't generate code that has equivalent performance.

The issue of compile time performance is irrelevant ... sub-millisecond differences, compared to (full) build times that are measured in minutes.

The real difference comes down to readability.  Some computations can be expressed more concisely using conditional expressions, and in some cases that makes the code more readable.   Readability *is* relevant because affects your and other peoples' ability to debug and maintain your code.

However readability depends both on the code and on the level of sophistication of the reader.  So it is hard make generalizations about the readability effects of using "advanced" constructs.

---

You give this as an example:

> ```
> if (condition 1) {
>      if (condition 2) {
>         if (Condition 3){
>             statement 1;
>         } else nothing;
>      } else nothing;
>   } else statement 3;
> ```
>
> versus
>
> ```
> if (condition 1 && condition 2 && condition 3) {
>      statement 1;
>   } else statement 2;
> ```

Firstly, the `&&` operator is a *logical* operator, NOT a *conditional* operator. (Yes, it is a short-circuiting operator, but that doesn't alter the fact that it is called a logical operator!!)  The *conditional* operator is the ternary `?` operator.

Second, the same arguments apply anyway, though the readability argument is (in most cases) slanted in favour of the `&&` (and `||`).  Only a total novice could have problems reading the second version of your code.

---

> I think short circuit evaluation is the another important reason besides readability. so should we conclude here?

In fact, this is not a difference at all.  The `&&` short-circuiting is equivalent to what you (can) get using nested `if` / `else` statements.  (The difference actually arises when you compare the `&&` and `&` logical operators.)

Comment: thanks friend, I think short circuit evaluation is the another important reason besides readability. so should we conclude here? Or anything new still we can learn. Aniket Thakur

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. sorry for my mistake. Then would it be a conclusion? @Stephen C

Comment: Conclusion - `&&` is more readable than nested if/else ... in most cases.

Comment: then what your speech about Short-circuit evaluation,you think? @Stephen C

Comment: @Newer - do you actually understand what I said there?  I said that `&&` and `if`/`else` **BOTH** do (or can do) short-circuiting.

Comment: Ok it is clear now. I am trying to learn from all of you, I am new in this line.  By the way Thanks all of you.......

Comment: +1. Nice, answer. I would add that with the nested `if` approach, it is possible to give more concise error messages then without. So I would change to the `nothing` to maybe `statement2_1`, `statement2_2` or to `handle_condition1_not_met` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Their correct names are tertiary/ternary operator/statement. And no, the bytecode/binary code should be the same as in an "ordinary" if.

Comment: The operator is often also _referred to_ as "the" ternary operator, because in all the mentioned languages it is the only ternary operator (as far as I know). But to call that it's _correct_ name is rather misleading.

Comment: Your're right. I apologize.

Comment: No need to apologize - just edit your answer. Especially since the OP has clarified in the meantime that he didn't even think about using the conditional operator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there would be a benefit in the performance.

From the code perspective, it would simplify the if-else block. But again, it will become complex and difficult to maintain if you try to implement nested if-else using ternary operator.

Comment: The OP has confused us by incorrectly using the term "conditional" when he actually means something else. Look at his example.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I have edited my question.